# Date format incorrect

Tags: sql, spring, oracle

I have a Spring Boot project with an Oracle db. I have the below script that I inserted in the db

```
insert into SEMESTER (SEMESTREID, CODE, ENDDATE, STARTDATE) values ('103', '1', TO_DATE('13-DEC-21','dd/MM/yyyy'), TO_DATE('06-SEP-22','dd/MM/yyyy'));
```

When I get the data from swagger, I noticed that the date is incorrect, it returns 0022 instead of 2022.

```
{
    "semestreId": "103",
    "code": "1",
    "startDate": "0022-09-06",
    "endDate": "0021-12-13"
}
```

Comment: How are `13-DEC-21` and `06-SEP-22` conforming to the pattern `'dd/MM/yyyy'`? I'm surprised this didn't result in an error.

Comment: Congratulations!  You just defeated the work that the entire IT community was laser focused on 22 years ago.  You just re-created the Y2k problem.   NEVER, EVER rely on 2-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper date literals:

```
insert into SEMESTER (SEMESTREID, CODE, ENDDATE, STARTDATE)
    values (103, 1, date '2021-12-13', date '2022-09-06');
```

Note that I removed the single quotes around `'103'` and `'1'`.  They look like numbers, so insert numbers.  If they are really strings, use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked it to convert a 2-digit year when the format mask is expecting a 4-digit year:

```sql
TO_DATE('13-DEC-21','dd/MM/yyyy')
```

This means that it is converting the value to 13th December 21AD (in the 1st century).

The output from swagger is correctly displaying the date that you told it to input.

Fix the input script to either:

- Match the format model to the input and use a 2-digit mask on the year:

  ```sql
  insert into SEMESTER (
    SEMESTREID, CODE, ENDDATE, STARTDATE
  ) values (
    103, 1, TO_DATE('13-DEC-21','DD/MON/YY'), TO_DATE('06-SEP-22','DD/MON/YY')
  );
  ```
- Match the input to the format model use a 4-digit year:

  ```sql
  insert into SEMESTER (
    SEMESTREID, CODE, ENDDATE, STARTDATE
  ) values (
    103, 1, TO_DATE('13-DEC-2021','DD/MON/YYYY'), TO_DATE('06-SEP-2022','DD/MON/YYYY')
  );
  ```
- Use date literals:

  ```sql
  insert into SEMESTER (
    SEMESTREID, CODE, ENDDATE, STARTDATE
  ) values (
    103, 1, DATE '2021-12-13', DATE '2022-09-06'
  );
  ```